# SAP Java JCO Program id

Tags: java, jco

I have to get some data with java from a sap.

I want to use sap jco, the connection works fine. But the other company is telling me I have to register to a program id.

So I tried `DestinationDataProvider.JCO_TPNAME` in my connection Properties. 
But to retrieve some data, I have to call some SAP function? Or can the program somehow be executed?

The SAP team has no experience with java jco and I have not much experience with sap. Can anybody help me?

Comment: You might have to be a bit more specific and add your code for somebody to be able to help.

Comment: registering program IDs sounds like building a RFC server with JCo. That would mean you would _receive_ some information from the SAP system, not _get_ information on your own.

Comment: Okay, that is interesting, i will have a look on the server example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to build an JCO Server, where I can register to a program id and get updates from the SAP system. On my first step I tried to build a JCO Client, which was wrong

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to connect to SAP destination, then in order to extract data you can call an SAP function module (which should be **RFC enabled**).

---

See the following example to execute an SAP function module using JCO (I assume that you are successfully able to connect to SAP).

1. **Get the SAP destination**

> JCoDestination destination =
>   JCoDestinationManager.getDestination(***DESTINATION_NAME***);

2. **Get the function**

> JCoFunction function =
>   destination.getRepository().getFunction(<**NAME_OF_THE_FUNCTION**>);

**3. Set the importing parameters**(if any)

> function.getImportParameterList().setValue(<**PARAMETER_NAME**>,
>   <**PARAMETER_VALUE**>);

4. **Execute the function**

> function.execute(destination);

5. **Get the return values from exporting parameters of the function module**

> function.getExportParameterList().getString(<**PARAMETER_NAME**>);

---

Additionally, you can see the following [link](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_nwpi711/helpdata/en/48/634503d4e9501ae10000000a42189b/content.htm) to see how to work with JCO.

---

If you want to build an RFC server using JCO, the following [link](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_nwpi711/helpdata/en/48/708027872c1b5ae10000000a42189c/content.htm) might be useful.

Comment: Thank you for your answert, but the sap company just gave me the connection details and a program id, where I should register to. I don't know  what they mean, they don't give me some function name to call

Comment: As @Dirk Trilsbeek mentioned in the comment, registering program IDs sounds like building a RFC server with JCo, which would mean you would receive some information from the SAP system, not get information on your own. Check this [link](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_nwpi711/helpdata/en/48/708027872c1b5ae10000000a42189c/content.htm) out for the same.